# std::thread increses DLL reference count, which prevents the unloading of the DLL

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll, reference, stdthread

I have a windows c++ dll which gets loaded by a third party program. I recently added a thread pool (this one https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool/blob/master/ThreadPool.h).

But now the dll get no longer unloaded when the third party program no longer needs it. The reason is that every thread spawned in the thread pool increases the dll reference count by one.
One problem is that I don't know when the third party program no longer needs the dll, so I can't manually shutdown the thread pool before, to reduce the reference count.

So my question is, is there a way to create a thread without increasing the dll's reference count?
And if so, when the dll gets unloaded do I need to manually shut down the thread pool ?

Side note: I use vs 2019 and c++17.

Comment: How do you increase the dll reference count? And why don't you decrease the reference count again at the thread end?

Comment: The reference count gets automatically increased when the thread pool starts its threads (by one for each thread). And the problem is, that it's a thread pool, there is no end until the thread pool gets shutdown. And the next problem is, I don't know when the program don't needs the dll anymore, so I can't shutdown it beforehand.

Comment: I don't see any increasing of the dll reference count ini the threadpool source you linked above. So where does this happen?

Comment: It seems to happen every time a thread is created. so  in line 38 `workers.emplace_back(`

Comment: In that case each thread of the thread pool should decrease the dll reference count again when it is finished. Does that not happen?

Comment: Yes if I shout down the thread pool manually the reference count decreases again. The problem is that for the dll to function properly, the thread pool needs to be running since some functions of the dll distribute work to it.
But since I do not know when the program no longer needs the dll, I cannot shutdown the thread pool manually.

Comment: OK, I think I understand the problem now. So there is no function called of the dll to signal that it is no longer used? Then you are probably out of luck. Because if the threads wouldn't increase the dll reference count, you would get a crash once the executable called `FreeLibrary`.

Comment: Yes exactly that is my problem... But thanks anyway, I had the hope that it would be possible somehow.

Comment: To make this work, you need *two* DLLs.  Then the reference count of the client application's `LoadLibrary`/`FreeLibrary` can be separate from the reference count keeping the thread code alive.

Answer (score 0):

And what about DLL_PROCESS_DETACH does it called? If so you should join threads in it.

Comment: DLL_PROCESS_DETACH is unfortunately not called because ther ref count is too high.